# Solr Cloud as windows service

Tags: windows, solr, windows-services, solrcloud, procrun

I am trying to start Solr Cloud as windows service using **Procrun** but I can not find working solution how it can be done. Maybe there is some solution how to do this?

I have tried to setup Solr Cloud using this article - https://opensourceconnections.com/blog/2013/08/27/solrcloud-as-a-windows-service/ but it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use the NSSM tool (Non-Sucking-service-manager) that fits your requirement to setup Solr cloud on Windows as a service.

The detailed steps for implemetation are listed in the below link
[How to Run Solr as a Service on Windows](https://www.norconex.com/how-to-run-solr5-as-a-service-on-windows/)

Comment: Thanks, I will try.

Answer (score 0):

For powershell with solrcloud and using zookeeper ensemble, please run
&"$nssm" install solr $ScriptPath start -cloud -p 8984 -z """""""$solrSvrArrayCsv""""""" -f

$nssm is the path to your nssm exe
$scriptPath is the path to your solr.cmd file
$solrSvrArrayCsv is a comma seperated array of zookeeper ensemble nodes ie) "zookeeper1:2181,zookeeper2:2181,zookeeper3:2181"
It must be wrapped in double quotes

This works for me launching solr cloud with ssl